# How is the ListViewItem.ListView property set?

Tags: c#, .net

The ListViewItem.ListView property will automatically be set after being added to a owner ListView. However the ListViewItem.ListView property has no setter.

`ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(); // item.ListView == null here.`
`listView.Items.Add( item ); // item.ListView != null where no setter.`

I'd like to know the implementation of ListViewItem.ListView get property.
What a private field is set inside the ListView.Items.Add() method? And how?
I'm trying craeting similar class relationship as a relationship between ListView and ListViewItem.

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListViewItemCollection.Add` calls (indirectly) an internal method on `ListViewItem`:

```
internal void Host(ListView parent, int ID, int index)
{
    this.ID = ID;
    this.listView = parent;
    if (index != -1)
    {
        this.UpdateStateToListView(index);
    }
}
```

(you can see this code in a decompiler like Reflector or JustDecompile)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this! I fully understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Properties have underlying variables storing the values. Probably the implementation adding to the ListView sets this variable to the right value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I'm expecting same thing too but I've not been able to  find any ways to access to the variables externally..

Comment: There is a huge chance that it is unaccessable. You can add the item to a ListView with `ListView.Items.Add(ListViewItem);`, maybe you can modify the parent listview by readding it to another one (but don't forget to remove it from the previous one).

Comment: You mean there is no way to know how the variables are set?

Comment: You can try to decode the implementation of the Items.Add, but it does not really matter. There is a chance that the underlying variable is marked internal, so only codes in the same assembly can access it. Why do you need that?

Comment: I was very curious to know a technique implementing this. Because I was wondering there might be other way than using internal modifier or reflection. Anyhow I should get a decompiler. Many thanks!